# Installing Windows to a disk before installing in a computer

Tags: windows, windows-vista

I'm just wondering if this is possible because it would make life a bit easier if it was.  I have a friend that desperately needs to re-install windows after several years of use to restore some usabilty, but they're not too technical, so I am a bit worried about them doing the backup of their user folder.  I have an extra drive here so I was thinking it would be great if I could complete the part of Windows setup where Windows is "copying files" here on one of the drives I have, and then simply exchange drives in their machine and then hopefully the Windows install would go through all the device recognition, driver installs, etc. Then I could attach their old drive as external storage and copy everything over that I need. Is this possible?

I realize there are some bootup things that might not allow this, but at least in theory, it seems like it would be possible.  The initial part of setup is simply copying files and not really analyzing the system at all, and if I also copied the drivers folder to the new disk somewhere, I should have any drivers that the install might be pulling from the CD.

And yes, I know I can do a USB install to speed things up, but it would be a lot faster to just plug the drive in and have the Windows setup simply start.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you asking how to take an image?

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is [Sysprep](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721940%28v=ws.10%29.aspx). You can install windows in a VM, then use Sysprep to prepare windows on the drive for a new comuter. When you are done, you put the drive in the target computer and boot it. It is extremely useful.

Comment: It looks like this is what I am looking for, since I will be installing a version of Windows on their machine that I don't currently run myself.  I've been meaning to get familiar with VM, so this looks like my next tech project.  Thanks for the reply!

Comment: I think I may have messed this up.  I am thinking that what you mean is that I plug in a USB drive and install Windows to that, not to a virtual drive in my VM software (Virtual Box for me), and then sysprep the USB drive.  Is that correct?  

Trying to sysprep the virtual drive just gives me a sysprep crash, so not sure what is up with that...

Comment: I was saying to mount a physical drive directly in the VM, not a virtual drive, not sure if vbox can do that

Answer (score 0):

You can do this several ways, one way is to install Windows 7 on another PC that has your hard drive installed, once windows 7 is installed and you are at the desktop, navigate to this folder

C:\Windows\System32\sysprep

run the sysprep exe and set it to look like the image below and hit OK button, it will take a while to prep it, when it shuts down remove the hard drive and install it in the other PC and boot up. Windows will install all the drivers it has for that system, there may be some you have to install after you get to the desktop, check Device Manager for missing drivers.

[image]

Comment: cannot seem to remove the image at the top, weird.

Comment: Thanks for the image, but as in the top response, I am not going to be installing the same version of Windows 7.  I would assume that it's not advisable to install anything else before doing this, or would installing other software actually make things go faster?

Answer (score -1):

Is it possible? Yes. Is it advisable or bullet-proof? No.

In my time as a system/network administrator I tried this and basically figured out that there are some things that are done during normal installation that aren't necessarily done during a transfer. For instance, setup of particular drivers/software for target hardware.

This doesn't sound like much but it can result in significant oddities. For instance, I had two identical looking Dells but with slightly different hardware. Install/image from one resulted in non-boot (boot loops actually) when the drive was transferred to the other.

Of course, I've had success stories as well. The only way you'll ever know is to simply try.